# AS3: How to use Android default font to the textfield which is on external swf ?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, actionscript

I just need to know how to assign or change font to the textfield which i am getting through external swf file. I mean, i have added an external swf file on stage it contains a textfield. I am assigning to dynamically also along with that i need to change the font to Android device default font. So that i can use font without embedding on android application. Let me know if anybody knows.
The code which i am using is below

```
       var myLoader:Loader =  new Loader();
    var myURlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("embdTxtSWF.swf");
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderAdded);
    var ldrContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(null),null);
    myLoader.load(myURlReq, ldrContext);



    private function onLoaderAdded(eve:Event):void{
        eve.currentTarget.content.y = 400;
        var objMC:MovieClip = eve.currentTarget.content["_mc"] as MovieClip;

        var _txtFld:TextField =  objMC["testTxt"] as TextField;
        _txtFld.multiline = true; 
        _txtFld.embedFonts = false;


        var tFormat:TextFormat = _txtFld.defaultTextFormat;
        tFormat.color = 0xFF0000;
        tFormat.size = 20;
        tFormat.bold = true;
        trace("target name . "+_txtFld);
        _txtFld.defaultTextFormat =  tFormat; 
        _txtFld.text = "He is a very nice boy.";
        tFormat.font =   "Droid Serif"; //  "Arial"   //
        addChild(eve.currentTarget.content)
    }
```

Comment: Hi i need solution for this issue. Let me know if anybody has solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use "_sans" for font, that should render all the time without embedding.